# Modeling double has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm runing the project where I have 4 models, those are : guest, host, room, reservation.

```
# host.rb
has_many :rooms

# room.rb
belongs_to :host
has_many :reservations
has_many :guests, through: :reservations

# reservation.rb
belongs_to :guest
belongs_to :room

# guest.rb
has_many :reservations
has_many :rooms, through: :reservations
```

I'm able to call room and reservation in the guest with these code:

```
# reservations_controller.rb
def your_trips
  @trips = current_guest.reservations
end

# your_trips.html.erb
<% @trips.each do |trip %>
  <%= trip.room.room_name %>
<% end %>
```

**However**, I can't call guest who made the reservation in the host. How can I do that? I believe there's something missing in the active record association but I don't know what.

## Update 1

I added the reservation list for the host, here is the code:

```
# rooms_controller.rb
def reservation_list
  @rooms = current_host.rooms
  @reservedguests = @rooms.guests(params[:id])
end

# reservation_list.html.erb
<% @reservedguests.each do |reservedguest| %>
  <%= reservedguest.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

It gave me this error:

```
NoMethodError in RoomsController#reservation_list
undefined method `guests' for #<Job::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f8c69e65eb8>
```

However, when I tried do this command in rails console:

```
> @host = Host.find(1)
> @room = @host.room.find(1)
> @reservation = @room.reservation.find(1)
> @reservedguest = @reservation.guests.find(1)
> @reservedguest.full_name
=> "My name here"
```

which means it should be working. What did I miss?

## Update 2

After I tried @potashin by replacing these line:

```
#rooms_controller.rb    
def reservation_list
  @rooms = current_host.rooms
  @reservedguests = Guest.find_by(room_id: @rooms.pluck(:id), id: params[:id])
end
```

But, it gives me another error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RoomsController#reservation_list
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column guests.room_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "guests".* FROM "guests" WHERE "guests"."room_i... ^ : SELECT "guests".* FROM "guests" WHERE "guests"."room_id" IN (2, 1) AND "guests"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

What does it mean?

Comment: There are a number of other things which you can address, but it seems like `Jobs` must be here erroneously I imagine.

    # guest.rb
    has_many :reservations
    has_many :jobs, through: :reservations

I am guessing you meant `has_many :rooms, through: reservations`?

Comment: @BenHawker My mistake, Yes, I did a typo there. But still it won't work, my current condition is at Update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@rooms` is an array. `#guests` applies to a single room. You have a few options:

## Option 1

```
@reservedguests = @rooms.map(&:guests).flatten
```

## Option 2 *(appended)*

If you want to get really fancy, or are going to be looking at all the host's guests quite a lot:

**Model**

```
class Host
  has_many :guests, through: :rooms
```

**Controller**

```
@reserved_guests = current_host.guests
```

Comment: The first code is working. However when I tried the second, it gave me this error: Couldn't find Room without an ID.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the guests who have reserved one specific room? Or all the rooms at that host?

Comment: All the rooms at that host.

Comment: Oh, then ignore the second part, that doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: (The 'second part' referred to here has since been deleted from the post.)